# How can I customize Unity editor controls (hotkeys)?

Tags: unity

I have been using blender for quite some time so I know pretty much how it works, and I have just recently started using Unity.

I find the unity UI to be very confusing and hard to use, and I was wondering if there was a way to change the controls to be more blender-like. What I mean is, "shift + scroll" to pan, or just "scroll" to orbit.

Comment: The closest thing there is - `Edit -> Shortcuts`. But last time I checked there was no support to rebind this.

Answer (score 1):

You can rebind them:
just go to Edit-> shortcuts and then look at the command you want to rebind in the search box, **double click on it**, and then press the key or combination of keys you want on your keyboard
There is a helper at the top right showing you the assigned keys

[image]